# facebook post to app page as another app, or give our app permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I don't know if this is possible through reading the docs, we have an app that we want to post on other businesses pages that we work with but doesn't show up as posts by others, we effectively want to auto post to their pages.

My first idea would be to give our app editor permission for their page manually, but you can only add users to page roles.

My second idea would be to get "manage_pages" permission when they log in to OUR app, then save the access_token

for example https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v2.1

will list the pages you manage, but can that access token be used by another app to post?

Or is there a service out there that will allow us to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give permission to an app to post to pages. What you need to do is give permission for all your pages to a User and get that user to login to your application with the `manage_pages` permission. Your app should then find the access_tokens for all the pages and then post to each page.

The posts would appear as coming from the Page/App itself, but can be posted from a completely different application, providing you have a valid access_token for each page.

Have a [look at this tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/23/facebook-api-posting-as-a-page-using-graph-api-v2-x-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/) for how to post to a single page, then adapt it to work with multiple pages.